# How to make an error message in a batch script if the target isn't present?

Tags: windows, script, batch-file

I have made a batch script template that I can program to select a given target, but I would like the script to *also* throw a **custom** error dialog if the target is not already present on the end-users machine.

Here's my current script:

```
set targetfilepath=%TARGETPATH%
%SYSTEMROOT%\explorer.exe /select, "%TARGETFILEPATH%"
```

Could I incorporate this into my script? If so, where should I place it?:

```
IF NOT EXIST goto net send localhost "%MESSAGETXT%"
```

Comment: You can use `IF EXIST` to test if a path or file already exists and continue from there.

Comment: SuperUser is not a "Please write me a script" kind of service. If you google for IF and CMD you'll find plenty of examples. Feel free to edit your question with a more full script so we can help with small errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for specific scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I would also like to use a cleaner dialog for the error message. Can I incorporate such a method into the batch script?**

Yes, you can run [msgbox](http://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html) with a batch script using [wscript](http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-wscript.html) as in the example I provided below. Since you also indicated you wanted "*to use a cleaner dialog for the error message*" I used the top line to set a variable and [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) the batch script again but with the `/MIN` option to keep the batch window from being so noticeable. Simple remove the top line if you want to not use it.

### Batch Script

*Be sure to set the values for the variables `SET TARGETPATH=`, `SET msgboxTitle=`, and `SET msgboxBody=` for your needs accordingly.*

```
IF NOT DEFINED MINIMIZED SET MINIMIZED=1 && START "" /MIN "%~dpnx0" %* && EXIT

SET TARGETPATH=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test
IF NOT EXIST "%TARGETPATH%" GOTO :ERROR
%SYSTEMROOT%\EXPLORER /SELECT, "%TARGETPATH%"
GOTO :END

:ERROR
SET msgboxTitle=This is my Message Title
SET msgboxBody=This is my Message Body
SET tmpmsgbox=%temp%\~tmpmsgbox.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
WSCRIPT "%tmpmsgbox%"

:END
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
- [MsgBox](http://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html)
- [Wscript](http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-wscript.html)

Comment: Excellent! This worked very well, and is easy to add to an existing script. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
set MESSAGETXT="Your Text Goes Here"
set TARGETPATH="Your Path Goes Here"
IF NOT EXIST "%TARGETPATH%" GOTO ERROR
%SYSTEMROOT%\explorer.exe /select, "%TARGETFILEPATH%"
GOTO END
:ERROR
msg "Username" "%MESSAGETXT%"
:END
```

You almost had it.  SS64 is your friend when it comes to batch programming.  And general command line usage as well: [Here is their site.](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)  I have no affiliation with them.

EDIT:
Wow, yeah I made some bad assumptions there and just added the code without testing/looking at it.  Windows 7 doesn't have `net send` anymore but uses `msg` instead.  I've updated my answer and it works on my system.  You can add a `PAUSE` command at the end if you want the command line to stay visible until you press a key to get rid of it.

Comment: _Thanks!_ I had no idea that site existed, I know what  I'll be frequenting for info on batch scripting from now on. However, I tried your script, but it did not seem to work. Should there be a pause perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Unfortunately, the script provided by [@Blerg](https://superuser.com/users/608505/blerg) didn't work *(for me).</s> I ventured into [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/show-a-popup-message-box-from-a-windows-batch-file) and used it in tandem with @Blerg's script. The script is now able to throw an error message using this script that I threw together:

```
IF NOT EXIST "%TARGETPATH%" GOTO ERROR
%SYSTEMROOT%\explorer.exe /select, "%TARGETPATH%"
GOTO END
:ERROR
START CMD /C "ECHO The target could not be located because it does not exist! && PAUSE"
:END
```

*(All I had to do was replace the fifth line.)*

Even though this works, I would also like to use a cleaner dialog for the error message like this VBS script can make:

```
x=msgbox("%WINDOWTEXT%" ,0, "%WINDOWTITLE%")
```

Can I incorporate such a method into the batch script, or should I translate the batch script into a visual basic script?