# batch files (.bat)... what does set game=%1% mean? This batch file isn't working correctly

Tags: batch, images, iso-image, emulator, daemon

This batch file is supposed to assign a disc image file's path to the variable "game" then mount that image with a program call Daemon Tool's. Then a program called SSF is supposed to load the mounted disc image.

Unfortunately this batch file only loads the image that is already mounted. I am trying to understand each line in this file and I cannot find any help with the line....   set game= %1%     .... I understand it is assigning a variable to game but what is the variable? Here is the batch file's contents. Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
@echo off
set game=%1% 
set daemon="C:\Program-blahblah-\DTLite.exe"    
set emu="C:\Users-blahblah-\SSF_TestVer\SSF.exe"    
%daemon% -mount 0, %game%    
start /wait "" %emu%    
%daemon% -unmount 0
```

Comment: So this question is about you wanting it to work with the daemon and not some other solution, correct? I assume specifically you are not looking for an answer with some other suggested solution in place of daemon, correct? That's my interpretation so just wanting to hear you verify or clarify otherwise just in case.

Comment: I got the .bat to work however, is there a command to close the window AND run the code to launch %emu% simultaneously? It works great but if I could get the window to close on its own instead of after I close the program %emu% it would be PERFECT! Thanks!

Comment: Try putting `IF NOT DEFINED MINIMIZED SET MINIMIZED=1 && START "" /MIN "%~dpnx0" %* && EXIT` at the top of the script and then just run it again to see if that helps. See [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1225455/how-to-make-an-error-message-in-a-batch-script-if-the-target-isnt-present/1225769#1225769) with this solution and some description.

Comment: Otherwise consider running this with Task Scheduler to execute the script with the `Run with highest privileges` option selected. See [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1285057/make-executing-cmd-window-show-when-it-is-ran-by-a-task-scheduler/1285240#1285240) but you could go as far as using the `SCHTASKS /Run /TN "\path\JobName"` method to execute perhaps. There are some starting points for you to test with at least that I can think of quickly but I provided to sources **my answers** with more applicable detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the `%1%` is a mistake and should be `%1` and you should run the batch file with a parameter like the name of the game. e.g. `C:\blah>thebatfile thegame` That will be what `%1` refers to i.e. the first parameter.   You can view any variable with `echo %whatevervar%` or `echo %1` and  `echo %daemon%`  And you can remove the `@ECHO OFF` line so that you can see more of what is going on. And at any time in the batch file you could do `pause`(when running it it will pause after a line and you can do ctrl-c to exit),  or you can try a line that says  `exit /b`  to exit the batch file early.

While I think that might answer your question about the %1, it might not help you beyond answering your question.  Going beyond your question - Where are you getting this batch file from? It might have various issues with it that are dependent on the specifics of the executables that it is helping you to run.

You might be better off avoiding daemon tools. At one time it was great software, for years,  but then they added malware to it http://forum.daemon-tools.cc/showthread.php?t=30115  and https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/2yt9gb/be_aware_daemon_tools_lite_installs_malware_adware/   I suggest you use virtual clonedrive instead.

If you want to mount an image then first do it without a batch file. And to start the game, once the image is mounted, then run it without a batch file.

Once you can do it manually then you could try doing it with a batch file.

Comment: I got this batch file from the forums of the program I am using. It is called Launchbox it is a front end for emulators. It is a GUI where you put multiple game files and choose the programs to launch the games with. It works great but this particular emulator, SSF, cannot read Image files on its own. They must be read from a cd drive (or a virtual drive) instead. And this is where the issue begins.

Comment: @HellfireEternal  Yes but you don't need a batch file to do these things. You can manually mount an image. And you can manually start the emulator. Anything that a batch file can do, can be done manually.  Some old programs for example need a CD in the drive, or as in your case, mounting an ISO so it sees a CD Drive.. That can be done manually.

Comment: I got this batch file from the forums of the program I am using. It is called Launchbox it is a front end for emulators. It is a GUI where you put multiple game files and choose the programs to launch the games with. It works great but this particular emulator, SSF, cannot read Image files on its own. They must be read from a cd drive (or a virtual drive) instead. And this is where the issue begins.

I was assuming the set game=%1% portion was grabbing the file path from Launchbox. The problem with the batch file seems to be in getting the file path of the image file. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the game is the ISO. You mount the game. Then you run the emulator.

Comment: The link is https://forums.launchbox-app.com/topic/32800-ssf-auto-mountunmount-with-xpadder-command-lines/ if that helps

Comment: @HellfireEternal the guy asking the question at that link is saying he is able to mount things manually and he is just looking to automate it. You haven't even shown that you are able to mount it manually. As I say.. You should try it manually before doing a batch file.

Comment: Yes I can mount the Image just fine on its own. The launchbox program displays the games box art and then you click on the box art and the game launches with the correct program or emulator. So i need a batch file to automate the mounting process depending upon which game I click.

Comment: @HellfireEternal See this here for command help with the specific app as you understanding how this works is best since you got the script from a forum http://daemon-help.com/additionally/command/... this way you can read and test until you get it working as expected and then you can script out what works in your system. If you have trouble getting it to run as confirming the syntax is correct, then we need to understand how you are executing the process and such as it may be something at that level. Test the commands, etc. and get that confirming working manually first.

Comment: Maybe here too: http://daemon-help.com/ but I'm sure you get the point

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT  Also daemontools has really nice easy GUI, like the primary interface people use is the GUI, and makes it really easy to mount an ISO .. For some reason he isn't even using that.. most people use the GUI.. it's easier than using the command line to load an ISO. One should really be able to use that and understand that before the command line.

Comment: @barlop I believe there is a misunderstanding, I was able to mount the image with the Daemontools GUI just fine before posting this question. Regardless, the echo command helped me see the variables to troubleshoot which helped me so thank you! In the end the problem was just simply that I was pointing to the wrong executable. The command line arguments must be passed to DTagent.exe NOT DTlite.exe. So here is the end result...

Comment: set game=%1%


set daemon="C:\Progr...Lite\DTagent.exe"


set emu="C:\Users\...er\SSF.exe"


%daemon% -mount scsi, R, %game%


%emu%


%daemon% -remove R


exit

Comment: @HellfireEternal Glad you got it working but do try %1 instead of %1%.   I notice that %1% can work.. but I don't think it's correct. As an example, try this.. create a batch file that says `echo %1 %2`  vs  `echo %1% %2%`     and try `echo %1%2` vs `echo %1%%2%`  Call it passing two parameters e.g. `blah.bat a b`  See the ones with %2% give funny result.  The ones with %2 are fine. Similarly even if it works with %1 it should still be %1 and not %1% which if it works works by fluke.